# Centrar TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

queria saber como se hace para centrar un textview, ya que el titulo de la app me queda desfasado para la derecha  y no en el centro de la pantalla,
 gracias.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TituloApp"
    android:text="HOLA'"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:textSize="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"


    />
```

Comment: Nicolas en que layout (relative o linear) tienes tu TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` con un `layout_width` de `wrap_content` y eliminar el `android:paddingLeft="50dp"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/TituloApp"
    android:text="HOLA'"
    android:textSize="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Comment: gracias, solucionado

Answer (score 5):

Puede ser programaticamente :

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

o cambiando la propiedad directamente en el layout:

```
   <TextView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Android"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Puedes eliminar  `android:paddingLeft="50dp"` ya esta empujando tu vista a la derecha.
- Te sugiero cambiar  `layout_width="match_parent"` por `layout_width="wrap_content"` , ya que con `"match_parent"` esta ocupando todo el ancho de la vista padre.

#### Si deseas centrar tu vista pero en toda la pantalla horizontal y verticalmente, puede realizarlo con un `RelativeLayout`  y usar las propiedades

```
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TituloApp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saque el paddingLeft, y puse  android:gravity="center" pero el texto ahora esta hacia la izquierda y no se centra

Comment: Depende de lo que pregunte Nicolas, que tipo de Layout usas como contenedor?

Comment: RelativeLayout Elena.

Comment: entonces es la segunda opción:  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: muchas gracias Elena

Answer (score 1):

Ve al layout donde esta el componente `(Edittext)`, en el `XML` le pones este código al componente  `(android:textAlignment="center")` y luego en la actividad java le pones al componente `(tv_bienvenida.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);)`

```
---------Component XML----------
android:textAlignment="center"

-------java-----------------------
tv_bienvenida.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esto:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Desde código hay dos formas, aunque las dos son válidas:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

o

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
```